# Are there precision issues when comparing a copied value with the original value?

Tags: matlab, double, precision

Consider the following workflow:

```
A = [2/3 exp(1) 5];

match = interp1(A, A, 2, 'next');
```

The second command finds the value of A which is first after 2. Thus, `match` is equal to `exp(1)`.

I have two questions:

1. Can I expect that `A == match` always evaluates to `[0 1 0]`?
2. If `B = [exp(1) exp(1) exp(1)]`, what is the result of `B == match`?

Do the answers change if `exp(1)` were replaced by some other irrational or transcendental number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When copying a value in memory, any floating point errors that exist will be copied as-is because after-all the copy operation is simply copying the bits over to a new location in memory and there is no arithmetic actually being performed and no new precision errors will be introduced.
   Because of this, a comparison between a floating point number (with precision errors) and a *exact* copy of that number will always be equal.

   That being said, your example assumes that the implementation of next-neighbor interpolation in `interp1` simply copies the data. While this may be true in the current release, this is definitely subject to change. If in the future, `interp1` was re-written to instead perform some floating-point arithmetic for next-neighbor interpolation, your comparison would then unexpectedly fail. Because of this I would discourage the use of `==` for comparisons, even in this case.
2. Differences in floating point errors (for the same calculation) are typically caused by a different *types* and *order* of operations. For your example of `exp(1)`, one would expect that the built-in `exp` function would perform an identical order of operations and therefore, for the same (identical) input, the output values would all have the same precision errors. Because of this, your comparison would yield `[1 1 1]`.

   Again, this makes an *assumption* about the internals of a built-in function which could ultimately come back to bite you. For this comparison also, I would avoid the usage of `==` just to make sure that your code functions as expected regardless of MATLAB's internal implementation of a function.

**Update**

Instead of doing comparisons like you've shown to try to identify the location of the next neighbor, I would probably just do the following to get the same result.

```
ind = find(A > 2);
```

Or if you really need a logical array.

```
[0 diff(A > 2) == 1]
```

Alternately, you could always find the value in `A` that is closest to the match using something like:

```
[~, ind] = min(abs(A - match))
```

**Update 2**

For the example that you provided in the comments

```
C = [exp(1) exp(1) exp(1) 1 1 pi*4 pi*4 pi*4 pi*4];
C == mode(C);
```

You are making the (reasonable) assumption that `mode` returns an exact copy of the value that was found to be the mode. The issue though in the comparison above, is that you're *also* making the assumption that all occurrence of `pi*4` in your input array are *also* exactly equal. So basically, if `mode` returns an exact copy, the comparison `C == mode(C)` will return at *least* 1 match but could return as many as 4 matches depending on how "equal" all of the `4*pi` entries are.

Comment: is your recommendation only for the comparsion `B == match`, or for both comparisons?

Comment: Honestly, I would avoid both of them otherwise you are dependent upon MATLAB's internal implementation of `interp1`. If they ever changed it (so that some floating point arithmetic was actually performed) it is possible that your comparison would then fail.

Comment: ok, so this leads to another question: how would you find the index in `A` of the the matched value? I.e. return `i` so that `A(i)` equals `match`?

Comment: @Alex It's a little confusing what you're trying to do. I'm not sure why you can't just do `i = find(A > 2, 1, 'first')`. Apart from that, you'd just compare the absolute value of the difference between the `match` and `A` and return the smallest. `[~, i] = min(abs(A - match))`

Comment: I am trying to solve a more general problem: Matlab functions like `interp1` return a double value which is a copied value from an existing array. I then wish to find matches against this copied value, and want to know the cases where `==` will fail. While your advice is good for the problem posed in my previous comment, consider this: `C = [exp(1) exp(1) exp(1) 1 1 pi*4 pi*4 pi*4 pi*4];`. Let's find the values in `C` that occur the most. I would have used `C == mode(C)`. But you are suggesting that I should not do such a comparison.

Comment: @Alex I guess that's my point. You don't know that `interp1` actually returns an exact copy. I would hope it does, but it's best to not assume. I would always do my comparison by comparing the absolute differences to a very small epsilon.

Comment: @Alex Yes so based on #1 in my answer, the comparison (if it really is copying the value) is valid. Remember though that this assumes that all occurrences of `exp(1)` and `pi*4` in your input vector are *also* all exactly identical. So if you're absolutely certain that `mode` returns a copy of the value and all the "duplicates" in your input are really identical copies, then you should be ok.

Comment: Ok thanks, this discussion has been very helpful in helping me understand when it might be acceptable to use `==` to make floating point comparisons.